# Does isPrintingAvailable check for multitasking support?

Tags: objective-c, ios, printing

Does the method `isPrintingAvailable` of the `UIPrintInteractionController` check if the device support the multitasking?

Or have I check this separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isPrintingAvailable simply checks to see if printing is available for the device - and nothing else. You can see the documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIPrintInteractionController/isPrintingAvailable

Comment: but what does it mean "check if the printing is available"? It's not clear to me.

Comment: It only checks to see if the device can print.  If the SDK supports it, it will be YES.

Comment: if it was so, it should be enough to check if the class UIPrintInteractionController exists or not, it would mean that the device runs 4.2 iOS. So, it's for this that I think that maybe the isPrintingAvailable checks also if the device supports multitasking.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that it will work that way.  If Apple gives users a setting to enable/disable printing on the whole device, your method will not work.  Only use the property for what it was intended, or else you will regret it.

Comment: :Now I understand, so I have to check for multitasking support separately.

Answer (score 1):

This does not check for multitasking and you shouldn't assume that multitasking is available if printing is available (although I guess that is the case for all devices now, but I'm not sure about this).

The way [Apple recommends to check this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW11) is:

```
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
   backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
```

Comment: Really, the thing that isn't clear to me is: what does it mean "isPrintingAvailable returns a Boolean indicating whether the device supports printing"? When a device support printing? if the AirPrint feature is supported from 4.2 iOS with multitasking, I suppose that the isPrintingAvailable checks for that...

Comment: While the *operating system* does support multitasking Apple does not support it on all *devices*. So the check whether multitasking is available is two-fold: first, does the OS support it (does the property `multitaskingSupported` exist ?) and then whether it is actually enabled on the current device (does `multitaskingSupported` return YES ?). For example, it will return NO on an iPhone 3G and iPod Touch 2G, even though both can run iOS 4.2. Printing is an entirely different matter that has nothing to do with whether multitasking is supported or not.

Comment: From Apple doc: "Printing was introduced as a system feature in iOS 4.2. It is supported only on those devices that support multitasking."